# Problem using own command within tabular header

Tags: tables

I have created a new command with `\newcommand` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\tC}[1]{@{\hspace{0.1em}}#1@{}}
```

In turn I have tried to use this new command in the creation of tables as follows:

```
\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|\tC{l}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|\tC{c}|}
    {\small Tonalidad} & {\small 7 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$} & {\small 6 $\flat$}
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{table}
```

However I get the following error:

```
 Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\tC): `c' used.
```

Additional information:
I have tested the code in TeXworks and it works.
I get the error in [ShareLatex](http://sharelatex.com).
In advance thanks for the help.

Comment: This 'can't' work this way, I think. It doesn't work on TeXLive 2017. TeXWorks is an editor and not a TeX distribution. You should use the `\newcolumntype` macro from the `array` package

Comment: `\newcolumntype{f}[1]{@{\hspace{0.1em}}#1@{}}` and     `\begin{tabular}{|f{l}|*{15}{f{c}|}}` seems to give what you want to achieve

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Done...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Macros inside the column specification slot of a tabular are tricky, only Black TeX Wizardry will work.

I suggest to use a new columntype with `\newcolumntype`, give it a unique name, say `f` and add the specifications there, e.g. the `\small` instruction can be used there as well.

Since there are 15 columns of the `c` type, `*{15}{f{c}|}` can be used as a short circuit solution.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

%\newcommand{\tC}[1]{@{\hspace{0.1em}}#1@{}}

\newcolumntype{f}[1]{@{\hspace{0.1em}}>{\small}#1@{}}

In turn I have tried to use this new command in the creation of tables as follows:


\begin{table}[ht!]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|f{l}|*{15}{f{c}|}}
      Tonalidad &  7 $\flat$ & 6 $\flat$ &  6 $\flat$ &  6 $\flat$ &  6 $\flat$ &  6 $\flat$ &  6 $\flat$ &  6 $\flat$ &  6 $\flat$ &  6 $\flat$ &  6 $\flat$ &  6 $\flat$ &  6 $\flat$ &  6 $\flat$ &  6 $\flat$
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Caption}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]